# Changing UIImageView dynamically

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSMutableArray *coolImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"active-1.jpg", @"active-2.jpg", @"active-3.jpg", @"active-4.jpg", @"active-5.jpg", nil];
}

-(void)someMethodWithData {


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableString *inactiveString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

            for (int i = 0; i < progress; i++) {
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[coolImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];

                inactiveString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"inactive-%d.png",i];

                [imagesArray addObject:imageView];
            }

            UIImage *setImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive-1.png"];
            for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++) {
                [(UIImageView*)[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] setImage:setImage];
            }

        });

}
```

This will always set the last or i(th) image correctly. It will not loop and change all the images I need. Is there another way to manage this?

Comment: The code you posted should set every image view in the array to the same image. Please clarify what is actually happening.

Comment: That is what I would like to happen. It is only setting the last image to "set-image.png"

Comment: Are you sure the array contains different image views and not just one or not the same one multiple times?

Comment: If you are using the loop,you can't see the difference in changing the images,anyway it will be the last image where the loop ends and you can see the last image unless you follow some other mechanism

Comment: @T_77 No, that's not the issue. The loop is meant to change several different image views to the same image, not the same image view to different images.

Comment: Are you adding the UIImageView's in interface builder then linking them with IBOutlets? Or are you dynamically adding them in the code..

Answer (score 1):

imageView is pointing to one UIImageView object and in a loop you are changing the image of imageView not adding new UIImageView object to your array. All the objects inside the array pointing to 1 UIImageView object. So it is so normal that you can only change the last object's image only, because there is no other object in your array.
you should do it like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableString *inactiveString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

            for (int i = 0; i < progress; i++) {
                UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];
                temp.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[coolImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];

                inactiveString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"inactive-%d.png",i];

                [imagesArray addObject:temp];
            }

            UIImage *setImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive-1.png"];
            for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++) {
                [(UIImageView*)[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] setImage:setImage];
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would create the image once so as to save memory.

I would also cast the object to a UIImageView (Not sure how that isn't getting flagged in xcode).

Lastly I would wrap it in a dispatch_async() to make sure it's happening on the main UI thread, because it could be getting called on a background thread and somehow the last image makes it to the main run loop, either way this is what it would look like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
UIImage *setimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"set-image.png"];    
for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++) {                
        [(UIImageView *)[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] setImage:setimage]];
    }
});
```

Comment: You are not saving any memory pulling out the `imageNamed:` call. That method always returns a cached image. And the cast for `UIImageView *` is not needed. And the use of `dispatch_async` probably isn't needed. The OP already said at least one image view is set properly. It's that some don't. Even if the code is running in the background, moving it to the main thread won't fix the issue. Summary - nothing suggested in this answer will help and most of it isn't necessary.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, well in that case the code won't hurt, but will make things clearer (the casting) and neater. But as for the dispatch_async, I have had problems where my UI won't update because a method was called in a background thread, and never knew that it needed to update the UI, even though it would eventually run it, so it could be useful in some cases.

Comment: @SnoApps Using your code didn't hurt but didn't solve the problem either. I'm still only able to update the last image in the loop i(th) image.  Thanks,

Comment: @user3662516 how are you putting the image views in the array?